# Domain of Function Not Specified For Determining Limit At Point

Tags: real-analysis

The problem motivating my question is the following (from Bartle and Sherbert's Introduction to Real Analysis).

> Example: $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} $ does not exist in $\mathbb{R}$

The text goes about showing this by first saying "let $\phi(x):=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$". **It is this first step which I don't understand** (the rest of the proof goes about by finding a sequence $ x_n $ that converges but for which $ \phi(x_n) $ does not and I understand why this proves the example above). Maybe it's just the way the text was written, but **it seems to me like I'm choosing a convenient domain for this function** (one not specified by the example) in order to show that the limit does not exist. Other examples in the text also fail to specify a domain and the domain is instead *specified in the solution*. **This pattern gives the reader the impression that one can merely specify whatever domain they want in order to show what the limit of a function is at a point or that it doesn't exist.**

Question 1: Can one simply choose whatever domain they want for a function in order to show that a limit does or does not exist? If so, what is the reasoning?

Question 2: Wouldn't the existence of limits depend on the function's domain? If so, I don't understand how the answer to Question 1 would be in the affirmative.

Comment: Friendly advice: This is a huge wall of text. Could it be trimmed down at all? That will help attract potential solvers for you. All the best.

Comment: To get you started with help: "it seems to me like I'm choosing a convenient domain for this function" You definitely are! Why is that okay? The limit should always be the same no matter what path you took to get to your point of interest, speaking loosely.

Comment: Looking at the example, unless specified otherwise, the limit is a two sided limit, and you need to consider values of $x<0$  If you wanted to only consider the the right side of $0,$ you would have to specify that $\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+} f(x)$

Comment: @the-count From the Divergence Criteria since there **exists** a sequence $(x_n \neq 0)$ in the domain $x>0$ for the function $\frac{1}{x}$ for which $(x_n \neq 0)$ converges but the sequence $\frac{1}{x_n}$ diverges, $\frac{1}{x}$ does not have a limit. I'm now seeing that since this is true if the domain of the function was restricted to $x>0$, then it would still be true if the domain was restricted to $|x|>0$. That answers the mystery with the example problem dropping $ x<0 $ from consideration in the domain, right?

Comment: Your example of $|x|>0$ is a little unconventional, but yes, I believe you've got it.

Comment: Thank you The Count and Doug M. You've helped me get to the answer and feel confident that I understand what's going on :)

Comment: @hgil that's great news! happy to help!